# X3d files don't get imported correctly

Tags: mesh, texturing, objects, import

[image]

I have tested opening multiple .x3d model files in Blender and all have the same issue but when I open them in other software they work fine.

I have edited the `init.py` script and import x3d.py script after which I was able to load the models by `bpy.ops.import_scene.x3d()` but they load without textures and mesh and having names all with index face set, so any script to help me handle the issue or a solution to this problem would be highly appreciated .

[image]

This is the original model and the model that imports into Blender looks like this.

[image]

This is example of one model I have tested multiple all give same kinds of result and some even don't get import .

Comment: but you are in solid mode in blender, it has textures in material preview or not?

Comment: sir you are the best I can't thank you any more I just came to know about the mode and thing

Comment: I mean you can accomplish the look like above in blender as well if you set it for solid preview, but that is only opinion-based... you need to switch to material preview or live render a preview for materials/texture and lighting to be visible on your models. I would suggest for you to find basics about Blender viewport and materials

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bq18i.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bq18i.jpg) so now the model is being loaded fine as I changed the mode but the floor isn't coming which is in the file and the errors still remain there I am attaching the hyper link to the init.py file and importx3d.py file that I had edited to be able to load x3d files of old format too in blender 2.9 https://github.com/AffanAhmedUsmani/AffanAhmedUsmani/blob/main/__init__.py https://github.com/AffanAhmedUsmani/AffanAhmedUsmani/blob/main/import_x3d.py

Comment: thanks alot sir but the floor aren't coming and the errors still remain there can you guide me further